# Amazon Android SDK for integrating Amazon Pay in Android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-pay

I was interested in integrating Amazon Pay as an option for the users in India to pay but was unable to find any proper documentation regarding it.

Instead, I found the following Note by Amazon:

> Note: The Amazon Pay and Login with Amazon services have been designed and developed for use within a web browser only. Our services cannot be used within a native application (including, without limitation, iOS, Android, RIM, and Windows operating systems). Amazon Pay reserves the right to suspend the payment account of any user of our services that has implemented our services within a native application.

Ref: [Amazon Pay and Login with Amazon introduction](https://pay.amazon.com/us/developer/documentation/lpwa/201985870)

Also, note the following page I found was intended for the USA. The complete section is missing when I select India region.

I am able to see Amazon Pay as a payment option in popular apps like BookMyShow, RedBus, etc.

Can somebody help me find some proper closure on this? :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: Did you solved this?